# how load video only once if a modal is dynamic in vuejs3/vite?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, vuejs3, prefetch, vite

I having a problem optimizing the performance of my application build in Vuejs3/Vite and Aframe. I need to somehow prefetch 6 videos. The problem is that each time I open a modal the browser fetches a video again. I want the browser to only fetch it once and store it somehow.

My application should look like this. Homepage has 6 buttons. On click, each button opens a modal. Inside the modal there a 6 videos. So, when a user clicks on the 2nd button the modal opens and inside it is only the 2nd video playing automatically. When a user clicks on a "close" button the modal is closed and the video is paused.

Right now my code looks like this:
HTML template

```
// 6 button-images like this
<a-image
   class="link"
   src="/play-new.png"
   sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"
   @click="openVideo(0)"
   position="-5 1.5 -4.5"
   rotation="0 60 0"
></a-image>

// Modal
  <div
    v-show="isModalOpen"
    class=""

    <div v-for="(video, i) in videos" :key="i">
    <video :src="video.file" loop class="block" :class="i === currentVideo ? 'play' : 'hidden'" v-show="$nextTick(() => i === currentVideo && play(i))" />
     <div class="">
        <button @click="hideVideo" class="">X</button>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My JS:

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue'

const videos = [ {
  file: 'videos/1.mp4',
},
{
  file: 'videos/2.mp4'
},
{
  file: 'videos/3.mp4'
},
{
  file: 'videos/4.mp4'
},
{
  file: 'videos/5.mp4'
},
{
  file: 'videos/6.mp4'
}
];

const currentVideo = ref(-1);

const isModalOpen = ref(false);

function openVideo(videoIndex) {
  currentVideo.value = videoIndex; //videos[videoIndex].file;
  isModalOpen.value = true;
}

function hideVideo() {
  document.querySelector('.play').pause();
  currentVideo.value = -1;
  isModalOpen.value = false;
}

function play(index) {
  if (index == currentVideo.value) {
    document.querySelector('.play').play();
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}

</script>
```

Here what my network tab look like after I restart the page and open a modal. The initial load is red. The modal open is green.
[image: network tab]

What I've tried so far:
Instead of `v-if` I made it work with `v-show` because with v-if it is not fetched at all.

To sum it all up, how do I make a browser only load a video once and cache/store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping your component with `<keep-alive>` should work:

```
// Modal
  <div
    v-show="isModalOpen"
    class=""

    <div v-for="(video, i) in videos" :key="i">
    <keep-alive>
        <video :src="video.file" loop class="block" :class="i === currentVideo ? 'play' : 'hidden'" v-if="$nextTick(() => i === currentVideo && play(i))" />
    </keep-alive>
     <div class="">
        <button @click="hideVideo" class="">X</button>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[DOCS](http:////%20Modal%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20%20%20%20%20v-show=%22isModalOpen%22%20%20%20%20%20class=%22%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20v-for=%22(video,%20i)%20in%20videos%22%20:key=%22i%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvideo%20:src=%22video.file%22%20loop%20class=%22block%22%20:class=%22i%20===%20currentVideo%20?%20%27play%27%20:%20%27hidden%27%22%20v-show=%22$nextTick(()%20=%3E%20i%20===%20currentVideo%20&&%20play(i))%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20@click=%22hideVideo%22%20class=%22%22%3EX%3C/button%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%20%20%3C/div%3E)